# Gradle - How to get values from AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

Inside `build.gradle` for Android project

```
task runAndroidApplication(type: Exec, dependsOn: ':installDebug') {
    //TODO update Activity name below or find a way to get it from AndroidManifest.xml
    if (System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        // windows
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', "com.example.androidapptorun.MainActivity"      
    } else {
        // linux 
        commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', "com.example.androidapptorun.MainActivity"
    }
}
```

How to get value for main Activity from AndroidManifest for the default Activity? 
(Also if there are several activities, making logic to select one would make it long,
 while processing is to be inside Android tools)

Is there better way from android plugin then parsing `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

UPDATE: https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin can possible suit some needs, but I needed no-argument version to make quick run in Eclipse via http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187556/reading-android-manifest-file

Comment: That is to read `AndroidManifest.xml` from app during runtime. The question is about build system gradle, i.e. compile time, no Android classes.

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558157/reading-info-from-existing-pom-xml-file-using-gradle and XmlSluper http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper. Not so clean solution....

Comment: The gradle-android-command-plugin[1] does this for you. But ATM it doesn't support Windows. [1]https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin

Comment: Thanks for great link. Maybe in the future they will give nice API for manifest.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wrote this for ADT 20 (L), Gradle 1.12 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2`.

It works with flavors, build types (don't forget `myBuildType.initWith(existingBuildType)`), and `applicationIdSuffix`.

Put the following at the end of `android { ... }`:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.install) {
         tasks.create(name: "run${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Exec, dependsOn: variant.install) {
            description "Installs the APK for ${variant.description}, and then runs the main launcher activity."
            def getMainActivity = { file ->
                new XmlSlurper().parse(file).application.activity.find{ it.'intent-filter'.find{ filter ->
                    return filter.action  .find{it.@name.text() == 'android.intent.action.MAIN'} \
                        && filter.category.find{it.@name.text() == 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'}
                }}.@name
            }
            doFirst {
                def activityClass = getMainActivity(variant.processManifest.manifestOutputFile)
                commandLine android.adbExe, 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', "${variant.packageName}/${activityClass}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For libraries you need to change `applicationVariants` to `libraryVariants`: see [manual](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manipulating-tasks).

**Update**: ADT 20, Gradle 2.1 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.1`:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.install) {
        tasks.create(name: "run${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Exec, dependsOn: variant.install) {
            description "Installs the APK for ${variant.description}, and then runs the main launcher activity."
            def getMainActivity = { file ->
                new XmlSlurper().parse(file).application.activity.find{ it.'intent-filter'.find{ filter ->
                    return filter.action  .find{it.'@android:name'.text() == 'android.intent.action.MAIN'      } \
                        && filter.category.find{it.'@android:name'.text() == 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'}
                }}.'@android:name'
            }
            doFirst {
                def activityClass = getMainActivity(variant.outputs.processManifest.manifestOutputFile)
                commandLine android.adbExe, 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', "${variant.applicationId}/${activityClass}"

                // or without the XML hacking: commandLine android.adbExe, 'shell', 'monkey', '-p', variant.applicationId, '1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `XmlSlurper` class.

example:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest package="com.example.your.app">
```

and retrieve it in gradle

```
def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file("AndroidManifest.xml"))

// returns "com.exmaple.your.app"
manifest.@package.text()
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Comment: Also you can use `android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile` instead of `"AndroidManifest.xml"` to locate manifest file automatically