# Can android gradle resolve module libraries' dependencies automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

### Setup

I have an android project setup in such a way that: **Main** *depends on* **Module A** and **Module A** *depends on* **Module B**.

Both A and B are compiled to ***aar*** files and uploaded to local maven repository. And in Main project, the importing of Module A is explicit.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(group: 'com.test', name: 'ModuleA', version: '0.0.1', changing: true)
}
```

### Error

When running the Main project, it failed with *NoClassDefFoundError* at places where Module A uses Module B.

This error is gone once I explicitly import Module B into Main project.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(group: 'com.test', name: 'ModuleA', version: '0.0.1', changing: true)
    compile(group: 'com.test', name: 'ModuleB', version: '0.0.1', changing: true)
}
```

### Question

Can't gradle resolve the dependencies automatically? Or do I have to include all Module A's dependencies in the build.gradle of Main project?

I think it is related to the pom file generation, in pom file you can define dependency section. How do we let gradle know to include the dependencies in generating the pom file?

> Edit #1

The build.gradle for ModuleA is like the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile(group: 'com.test', name: 'ModuleB', version:'0.0.1', ext: 'aar', changing: true)
} 

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageId
            version = versionId
            artifactId libraryId
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-debug.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            maven = true
            username = "admin"
            password = "password"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a "provided" dependency of Module B in the Module A?

Comment: @AlbertoAnderickJr hmmm...I have a "compile" dependency.

Comment: try to put a provided dependency and then  you can use ModuleA and ModuleB dependencies as compile in the Main project

Comment: @AlbertoAnderickJr, do you mean in the build.gradle of ModuleA to have a "provided" scope import of ModuleB? I thought "compile" scope is both "provided" and "package"

Comment: package the ModuleB into ModuleA can be the cause of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find a solution for gradle to generate pom with dependencies, add the following to publishing task:

```
        pom.withXml {
            def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
            configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "automatically"? If the dependency does not exist in a defined path with well-defined names in your gradle.build, it will not find it. What may be misleading is that references to libraries in repositories can include dependencies to other libraries. When gradle requests the library location, the server responds with a file that specifies the location **and** dependencies, if applicable.

An `aar` file does not include your gradle.build or another dependency file that gradle can use, so any dependencies defined in your **Module A** gradle.build are not available to your main gradle.build. So you can't expect gradle to go to the source location of your **Module B** because it isn't there.

I think libraries in repositories do not make this clear because if a library with dependencies is in a repo then those dependencies seem to "magically" be included when you do a build. This is because the library reference can include references to the other dependencies and gradle is given that information when it requests the library. The repo library entry/definition includes dependencies.

If this is the type of behavior you are looking for, you should put your aar in a repo (public or self-hosted) and then create an appropriate library definition in the repo (like a pom.xml file), specify the dependency and add the dependency library to the repo also.

EDIT:

Also gradle does not support parsing pom files natively. So you cannot directly reference a pom file to identify dependencies. However, it will work with repositories that identify dependencies (and those repositories can use pom files, but gradle does not parse them). See the docs here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Also, see the related question about gradle's lack of support for parsing pom files: [Reading info from existing pom.xml file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558157/reading-info-from-existing-pom-xml-file-using-gradle)

Comment: Yes, I totally get what you mean there, if you look closer to my question, I have the following "I think it is related to the pom file generation, in pom file you can define dependency section. How do we let gradle know to include the dependencies in generating the pom file?"

Comment: gradle does not support parsing the pom file - see my edit.

Comment: Yea, I googled if gradle maven plugin supporting generating the dependency and got no luck. I guess I will have to include the child modules' dependencies in my parent project's build file then.